# Iterating through an array of objects with properties and printing them to the DOM

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml

We're trying to run through a collection of objects with properties (key: value)'s and write it to the dom.

```
var productContent = {
item1: {
    description: "description 1",
    price: 1,
    URL: "something1.com",
},
item2: {
    description: "description 2",
    price: 2,
    URL: "something2.com",
},
```

We've tried a few different types of code, such as:

```
var productInfo;
var insertProduct = document.getElementById("productList");

for (var i in productContent) {
    console.log(productContent[i]);
    productInfo += productContent[i];
}

insertProduct.innerHTML = productInfo;
```

Nothing seems to be working. Any thoughts on how to approach this? We've been able to get properties shown in the console but not much else.

Comment: Why are you storing your objects in another object? For your use case an array looks simpler.

Comment: What format do you want the data to be "written to the dom" in? A table? Some sort of list? You'll have to construct HTML elements to create the output you want; you can't just "output an object to the DOM"

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first codeblock has a syntax error. The productContent object is missing a closing curly brace: `}`.
2. You also have a comma after the last property instead of only between properties.

You should use the JS console in your browser's developer tools to debug this.

Comment: Of course we have used the Javascript console. However, it's got to the point, I'm not even sure we're in the write direction to have this work correctly.

Sorry - my mistake, we're not missing a curly brace I just got off other objects to make it smaller

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your script, you can **start** with following:

```
var htmlValue = '';

for (var productKey in productContent) {
    var product = productContent[productKey];
    htmlValue += 'description: ' + product.description + '<br>';
    htmlValue += 'price: ' + product.price + '<br>';
    htmlValue += 'url: ' + product.URL + '<br><br>'; 
}

insertProduct.innerHTML = htmlValue;
```

Errors:

1.

```
for (var i in productContent) {
```

This is just a strong suggestion, but you should change `i` to something meaningful for the context, such as `key` since you are iterating over object properties. Naming properly your variables will help you spot errors in your code.

2.

```
productInfo += productContent[i]
```

This is not the proper way to concatenate object values. First iteration and it will be "undefined[object Object]".

3.

```
insertProduct.innerHTML = productInfo;
```

What are you even trying to do here? You can't just put in element an object. You must put as code and formatted the way you want.

Comment: Never use `innerHTML +=`

Comment: @Oriol What's the reason for that?

Comment: @qxz Because it serializes the current content, concatenates as string, and then it reparses it all. It's just repeating the same work again and again. And when serializing, all internal data is lost.

Comment: @Oriol Meaning the DOM is converted to an HTML string, appended to, then completely re-parsed, right? Makes sense; would that also corrupt DOM nodes in JS vars?

Comment: @qxz Exactly, since the HTML would be reparsed, references to the old DOM elements will no longer be useful because they won't be in the document tree anymore.